# How to use location based services on kindle fire

Tags: android, gps, kindle-fire, location-based-service

i want to use location based services in my application.
How to do it on kindle fire?

Comment: you need soldering iron and gps module ...

Comment: @Selvin True, the Kindle Fire doesn't come with a GPS, haha.

Comment: Before down vote first learn or search Google, then down vote. I knew Kindle Fire doesn't come with a GPS, but there some apps that uses location based services, go to amazon store and search it...

Answer (score 2):

Skyhook offers a location [SDK for the Kindle Fire](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/location-technology/sdk.php) that allow app developers to easily include location in their apps. Several apps are available that [leverage this SDK on the Kindle Fire](http://www.mediabistro.com/appnewser/kindle-fire-app-gets-location-services-sans-gps_b21551) such as TweetCaster, MapQuest, HopStop and deCarta.

Answer (score 0):

[socketGPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.capsicumdreams.SocketGPS&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5jYXBzaWN1bWRyZWFtcy5Tb2NrZXRHUFMiXQ..%20%28socketGPS%29) on the Android market connects to an iPhone, to simulate a real GPS receiver on an android device without a GPS module.